# Getting an accurate count on this JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

This query is working fine.  It gives a count of contest entrants for whom the contact id in contest_entries is their origin_contact in the person table.

```
SELECT c.handle, COUNT(*)        
FROM `contest_entry` ce,         
person p,                        
contest c                        
WHERE                            
p.origin_contact = ce.contact AND
c.id = ce.contest                
GROUP BY c.id
```

I want to now query how many of those records also have at least one record where the contact id matches in email_list_subscription_log BUT that table may have many log records for any one contact id.

How do I write a join that gives me a count that is not inflated by the multiple records?

Should I use a version of my first query to get all of the contact ids into a tmp table and just use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which field is contact id, but you can do something like this:

```
select c.handle,
    count(*) as count
from `contest_entry` ce
inner join person p on p.origin_contact = ce.contact
inner join contest c on c.id = ce.contest
where exists (
        select 1
        from email_list_subscription_log l
        where l.contact_id = ce.contact
        )
group by c.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You ought to deflate the email_list_subscription_log with DISTINCT or GROUP:

```
SELECT c.handle, COUNT(*)        
    FROM `contest_entry` ce
    JOIN person p ON (p.origin_contact = ce.contact)
    JOIN contest c ON (c.id = ce.contest)
    JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT contact, email FROM email_list_subscription_log ) AS elsuniq
         ON (ce.contact = elsuniq.contact)
[ WHERE ]           
GROUP BY c.id
```

Using GROUP in the subquery you might count the number of records while still returning one row per element:

```
    JOIN (SELECT contact, count(*) AS elsrecords FROM email_list_subscription_log
          GROUPY BY contact) AS elsuniq
```

With this JOIN syntax, the WHERE is not necessary, but I kept it there if you need additional filtering.

Comment: Thanks!  For some reason your query is just hanging indefinitely.  Aborted after 30 mins.